# Eleventy - Cannot load tweet embed shortcode

Tags: javascript, eleventy

I am using eleventy for a personal blog project. My `package.json` looks like that:

```
{
  "name": "personal_blog_eleventy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "eleventy --serve",
    "build": "eleventy",
    "debug": "cross-env ELEVENTY_DEBUG=true npx eleventy"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@11ty/eleventy": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@11ty/eleventy-img": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

My `eleventy.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {

  const { imageShortcode } = require("./_data/image.js");
  eleventyConfig.addNunjucksAsyncShortcode("image", imageShortcode);
  eleventyConfig.addLiquidShortcode("image", imageShortcode);
  eleventyConfig.addJavaScriptFunction("image", imageShortcode);
  

  // Passthrough copy for landing_pages
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("landing_pages");
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("images");

  // Add a collection for blog posts
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("posts", function(collection) {
    return collection.getFilteredByGlob("pages/posts/*.md");
  });
  

  const { getTweetEmbed } = require("./_data/tweet.js");
  eleventyConfig.addNunjucksAsyncShortcode("tweet", getTweetEmbed);
 

  return {
    dir: {
      input: 'pages',
      includes: '../_includes', // Change this line to point to the correct _includes folder
      output: "_site"
    },
    passthroughFileCopy: true,
  };
};
```

My folder structure looks like the following:

```
$ tree -L 3 -I 'node_modules'
.
├── browser_extensions
│   └── url-annotator-extension
│       ├── css
│       ├── icon128.png
│       ├── icon16.png
│       ├── icon48.png
│       ├── js
│       ├── manifest.json
│       ├── popup.html
│       └── popup.js
├── _data
│   ├── image.js
│   └── tweet.js
├── images
│   ├── 300x200.png
│   └── 480px-Google_Chrome_icon.png
├── _includes
│   ├── blank.njk
│   └── layout.njk
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── pages
│   ├── index.njk
│   ├── landing_pages
│   │   ├── landing_page-1.njk
│   │   └── landing_page-2.njk
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── post-1.md
│   │   └── post-2.md
│   └── projects.njk
├── README.md
└── _site
    ├── images
    │   ├── 300x200.png
    │   ├── 480px-Google_Chrome_icon_(February_2022).svg.png
    │   └── 480px-Google_Chrome_icon.png
    ├── img
    │   ├── qeNuB8FlGc-300.avif
    │   ├── qeNuB8FlGc-300.jpeg
    │   ├── qeNuB8FlGc-300.webp
    │   ├── tDnvQu38B3-300.avif
    │   ├── tDnvQu38B3-300.jpeg
    │   └── tDnvQu38B3-300.webp
    ├── index.html
    ├── landing_pages
    │   ├── landing_page-1
    │   ├── landing_page-1.njk
    │   ├── landing_page-2
    │   └── landing_page-2.njk
    └── projects
        └── index.html

17 directories, 34 files
```

My `tweets.js` looks like the following:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function getTweetEmbed(url) {
  const apiUrl = new URL("https://publish.twitter.com/oembed");
  apiUrl.searchParams.set("url", url);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json.html;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching tweet embed:", error);
    return "";
  }
}

module.exports = { getTweetEmbed };
```

In my `post-1.md` I am trying to load a tweet like the following:

```
---
title: My First Post
date: 2023-04-18
layout: layout.njk
---

This is my first blog post using Eleventy!

{% tweet "https://twitter.com/Maxrocket_/status/1647363916236836865" %}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
$ npm run start

> personal_blog_eleventy@1.0.0 start
> eleventy --serve

[11ty] Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
[11ty] 1. Having trouble rendering liquid template ./pages/posts/post-1.md (via TemplateContentRenderError)
[11ty] 2. tag "tweet" not found, file:./pages/posts/post-1.md, line:4, col:1 (via ParseError)
[11ty] 3. tag "tweet" not found (via AssertionError)
[11ty] 
[11ty] Original error stack trace: AssertionError: tag "tweet" not found
[11ty]     at assert (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.node.cjs.js:297:15)
[11ty]     at Parser.parseToken (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.node.cjs.js:2130:17)
[11ty]     at Parser.parseTokens (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.node.cjs.js:2122:33)
[11ty]     at Parser.parse (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.node.cjs.js:2116:21)
[11ty]     at Liquid.parse (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.node.cjs.js:3499:28)
[11ty]     at Liquid.compile (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/Engines/Liquid.js:255:28)
[11ty]     at Markdown.compile (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/Engines/Markdown.js:68:28)
[11ty]     at TemplateRender.getCompiledTemplate (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/TemplateRender.js:269:26)
[11ty]     at Template.compile (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/TemplateContent.js:362:42)
[11ty]     at async Template._render (/home/admin/Desktop/Code/personal_blog_eleventy/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/TemplateContent.js:486:16)
[11ty] Wrote 0 files in 0.07 seconds (v2.0.1)
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if you need also to register Liquid in eleventy.js?